# Defining laravel route with special characters in url

Tags: laravel, routes

Issue is boss wants url to show this: example.com/special%A0
how do I define a route for this inside laravel? My current code is:

```
Route::get('/special{any}', function ($any) {
    return view('webdesign_special');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, this is the best way to go about it. If you want to compensate for special characters then you should do something like this.

```
Route::get('/{link}', function () {
    return view('webdesign_special');
})->where('link','special.*');
```

We are using Laravel 5.2, so hopefully this will help other users using Laravel 5.